shell script to open a new bash terminal profile and excute a command in VS code WSL
How to open a new bash terminal profile and execute a command in VS code WSL. This is the below shell script which I have written so far
#!/usr/bin/env -bash

xterm -e ls

sleep 2
xterm -e echo $PWD

sleep 2
xterm -e echo $TERM


Why do you need to open a terminal window for each command?

I'll replace those commands with binary file(.out) execution later.
